# Customise `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, custom-component

Developing a swing application where I need to redirect the user to another JFrame if he clicks the `No button` on a `JoptionPane.showConfirmDialog`. I wrote this code :

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    int a=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Did you complete your task?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
    if(a==1){
        RedirectedForm rf=new RedirectedForm();
        rf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But `if(a==1){...}` part does not seem to work. Even if I create a reference to the JFrame-`RedirectedForm` which I want to redirect to, the window gets disposed always. Can anybody explain the reason and suggest a solution to this?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!!

Providing both the java classes below :

***WindowClosing.java***

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WindowClosing extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public WindowClosing() {
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {
    window_close_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowClosing(evt);
        }
    });

    window_close_label.setText("Window Close Form");
    pack();
}                        

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    int a=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Did you complete your task?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
    if(a==1){
        RedirectedForm rf=new RedirectedForm();
        rf.setVisible(true);
    }
}                                  
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new WindowClose().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JLabel window_close_label;
}
```

***RedirectedForm.java***

```
public class RedirectedForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public RedirectedForm() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("You have been redirected to this Form becuse you have closed the previous one");

    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RedirectForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
```

}

I have edited the code once more, hope this will give a clearer idea about the problem

Comment: What does the Feedback class do?  That's the code we need to see, as well as the code that the formWindowClosing method is used in.  Create a short, self-contained, **runnable** Java application that illustrates the problem, and then we can help you.

Comment: Feedback class is just another form which has some `JLabel`, `JtextField` and `JButtons`. Nothing fancy at all. 
***Posting the code in my question***

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : Hope the code is as per you have wanted, as I have removed the declarations and other Layout and Image settings

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : I am pretty much sure that the `Feedback.java` is not disposing itself anywhere/or any bug is present in the code which automatically disposes it

Comment: Should not `fb.setVisible(true)` be called from another thread?

Comment: Can you please suggest the way of doing that? @Zereges.... I am still discovering things as a beginner.

Comment: `initComponents()` is undefined for both classes. Copy-paste both to your editor in a new project and fix **all** compilation errors. You also have a lot of unnecessary code, like the logging stuff and a lot of action listeners.

Comment: @user1803551 - I have clearly mentioned that declarations and initialization are not given as it would enlarge the code as I have done it in an IDE. But I have checked all classes, there are no errors and i can guarantee that.

Comment: This is still not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as requested in the *first* comment. You don't need to guarantee anything - my compiler gives compilation errors which are clearly correct.

Comment: I am providing the compiled, error free code @user1803551. But should I mention the code related to Layout, Panel, Button settings?

Comment: @user1803551 : Did you see my EDIT 2?

Comment: Yes, and the code is not confusing, it's just not compiling. Also, you will want to explain what a "*page*" is because this is not a browser. If you want a frame that when you click on a button changes its contents, then post code that tries to do that and only that (see also `CardLayout`)..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78619/discussion-between-mustangdc-and-user1803551).

Comment: @user1803551, Hope this is what is needed

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : Hope this is correct, precise and optimum

Comment: Close enough (still, put your code in a compiler and you'll see that you mistyped the names of the classes in the constructors; easy to fix though).

Comment: :) . Sorry for that but appreciate that you have corrected. Thanks!!! @user1803551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is probably that you set

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This causes the whole application to exit when you close the frame, regardless of which option you chose in the dialog. Nevertheless, you [shouldn't use multiple `JFrames`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), but instead [use `CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as demonstrated here:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    private String redirectedForm = "RedirectedForm";
    private String windowClosing = "WindowClosing";

    Example() {

        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(cl);
        add(new WindowClosing(), windowClosing);
        add(new RedirectedForm(), redirectedForm);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {

                int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Example.this, "Did you complete your task?");
                if (a == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    return;
                }
                if (a == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
//                  cl.next(frame.getContentPane()); // This to show the next card
                    cl.show(getContentPane(), redirectedForm); // This is to show a specified card
                }
                else {
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE );
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Example();
    }
}

class WindowClosing extends JPanel {

    public WindowClosing() {

        JLabel closeLabel = new JLabel("The WindowClosing panel");
        add(closeLabel);
    }
}

class RedirectedForm extends JPanel {

    public RedirectedForm() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("You have been redirected to this Form becuse you have closed the previous one");
        add(label);
    }
}
```

By setting `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` the `windowClosing` event will not terminate the program. Instead you choose what do do depending on the selected option: nothing, exit[,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) or switch panel.

#### Notes:

- Don't use the `int` values of static constants such as `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`, just use the reference to it instead.
- You might want to set an owner for the `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Thats is what I needed. Infact came to know about new concepts, will definitely implement that. Cheers and Thanks!!!